# How to Print Hexadecimal Numbers in PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, algorithm, base-conversion

I need to print some data (a little bit strange formatted). I was writing it in PHP with if ($num%10==9) but it was impossible for me to get correct output.

So take a look at this for example.
We have x of files in folder. For this example x=36. X is always known.

Output should look like this:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
10
11
...
19
1a
...
1f
20
...
24
```

Sorry for the such a long "list" but I believe that you know what I need now.
So, after each number which ends with 9 we have num(a,b,c,d,e,f) and then number which follows previous number with 9 on the end. (Ex. 3a...3f,40..49).
And what is most important is that the number of printed lines must be equal to x.

If possible, I would prefer PHP or Java code but I will be very grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Could you just say hexadecimal numbers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to print the numbers 1 to 30 in hexadecimal notation.  Try this method for each line:

```
dechex ( int $number )
```

Comment: so simple... `while($number++ < $X){ echo dechex($number)."\n"; }`

Comment: Ah, stupid me, I wasn't thinking about hex at all...
My brain ain't working at this hot days, but it's obvious that I am a real nOOb sometimes :D

Answer (score 30):

For Java:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(number));
```

or

```
System.out.println(String.format("%x", number));
```

The latter has more options for formatting the hex string.

Comment: Even slightly shorter: `System.out.format("%x\n", number);`

Answer (score 7):

```
    for ( int i=1 ; i <= x; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf("%02x\n", i);
    }
```

Comment: What is this? Java doesn't have printf.

Comment: As of Java 5.0, it does. http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Tech/Chapter05/formatterPrintf.html

Answer (score 4):

This will print hexadecimal 01-24 (with 0 padding in front of numbers less than 10)

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 36; $i++) {
    printf("%02x\n", $i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function blah($n) {
  for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++) {
    printf("%02x\n", $i);
  }
}

blah(36);
?>

01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
1a
1b
1c
1d
1e
1f
20
21
22
23
24
```