# What kind of number is aa568 and how do I convert to it from decimal in Java?

Tags: java, math, decimal

I assume `aa568` uses a different base than 10.

What type of number is this most likely?

And how do you convert a decimal number into this base using Java?

Comment: Possibly hex, though if it's an unknown base, it could very well just be base 11, or 12, or 13... you just don't know. But hex is most likely.

Comment: Or base-4 with the set of digits being 5, 6, 8 and a.

Comment: It's an obstetrical number. You should know that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is hexadecimal (0-9 + A-F instead of 0-9), you can convert it from hex to decimal as follows:

`int i = Integer.parseInt(hexStr,16);`

Where 16 is the base of the number system. Decimal is base 10, hexadecimal is base 16.
And back from decimal to hexadecimal:

`String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(i);`

Comment: Isn't this answering the wrong question? "Convert a decimal number *into* this base ..."?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be hexadecimal? If it is then just precede that by 0x ie. 0xaa568.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a number into a hexadecimal string can be done by the `Integer.toHexString()` method:

```
int number = 697704;

System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(number));
```

will print "aa568".

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that it's hexadecimal and more typically written 0xAA568 which is decimal 697704.

If you're asking how you would print a decimal number in a hexadecimal representation using Java ... see [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269573/how-to-print-hexadecimal-numbers-in-php-or-java).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of number may depend on the context, of none of the above fits, then it may be an integer sequence, I looked it up in the online encyclopedia of known integer sequences. Example a000045  is a Fibonacci sequence, (Formerly M0692 N0256), if it has to do with math it may also be a library reference to a paper written by AA. Only the Context can tell. Mathnet.ru  had one reference "The behavior of the Lebesgue constants of two-dimensional Fourier sums over polygons" which fits the questioned number aa568.