# Print hexadecimal as hexadecimal

Tags: java

```
 int hexNumber = 0x7A;

   System.out.println(hexNumber);
```

This will print 122, but what if I want it to print 01111010 and  0x7A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Print Hexadecimal Numbers in PHP or Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269573/how-to-print-hexadecimal-numbers-in-php-or-java)

Comment: Note that `int hexNumber = 0x7A` and `int hexNumber = 122` does *exactly* the same thing. There's no way to tell what the base of the integer literal was once the source is compiled.

Comment: Please understand something: there is no such thing as a "hexadecimal number" in a Java program.  `int hexNumber = 0x7A` is **exactly** the same as `int hexNumber = 122` or `int hexNumber = 0b1111010`.  There will be nothing in the program that "remembers" whether you used a hexadecimal, decimal, or binary integer literal to initialize it.

Comment: @zakinster I guess you win by 4 seconds...

Comment: I want to have direct access to the bits of my number, though. Be it read(user input) as hexa or decimal.

Comment: @user3383062 You have multiple possibilities to access each bits of an integer. Maybe you should describe what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Found my answer. Ty for your time.

Comment: An `int` is not a hexidecimal, or a decimal. It is a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Integer.toString(hexNumber, 16);
```

---

**See**

- [IDE one demo](http://ideone.com/n5wyFz)
- [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: or `Integer.toHexString(hexNumber)`

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to print it bit-by-bit?

Comment: @user3383062 `Integer.toString(n, 2)` ? You can iterate over the resulting string if that's what you want...

Answer (score 1):

> This will print 122, but what if I want it to print 01111010 and 0x7A?

```
Integer.toHexString(hexNumber);  // 7a
Integer.toBinaryString(hexNumber);  // 1111010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int hexNumber = 0x7A;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(hexNumber));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(hexNumber));
```